# scipy.signal.detrend within apply_ufunc failing for large array sizes

Tags: python, python-xarray

**What I am trying to do:** Detrend an xarray dataarray using scipy.signal.detrend called within xr.apply_ufunc

**What is the problem:** The MVE below works for small sizes (10000,1000,3) but fails if I progressively increase the array size (10000,10000,3) even when I have more than enough memory. I get a 'kernel died' message right after the apply_ufunc step is finished.

```
# Import stuff
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask_jobqueue import SLURMCluster
import scipy
from scipy import signal

# Launch cluster with 280 gb memory
cluster = SLURMCluster(cores=8, processes=8, memory="280GB",queue="medium",
                       walltime="02:30:00")
print(cluster.job_script())
cluster.scale(8)
client = Client(cluster)

# Create array
data=np.random.random([10000,1000,3])

# Superpose a linear trend at two locations
data[:, 0, 0] = data[:, 0, 0] + np.arange(data.shape[0])
data[:,-1,-1] = data[:,-1,-1] + np.arange(data.shape[0])

# Create xarray dataarray using above array
arr = xr.DataArray(data,dims=['t','y','x'])

# Rechunk to unchunk along core dimension and to get ~100mb chunks
arr = arr.chunk(dict(t=-1,y=500))
# array size
arr.nbytes/1e9
# Output: 0.24

# apply_ufunc call
test_detrend = xr.apply_ufunc(scipy.signal.detrend,arr,kwargs=dict(axis=2),
                              input_core_dims=[['t']],output_core_dims=[['t']],
                              dask='allowed',vectorize=True)

# Plot below shows the detrending works correctly
arr.isel(x=-1,y=-1).plot()
test_detrend.isel(x=-1,y=-1).plot()
```

[image: Validation of detrending calculation]

Comment: are you sure `apply_ufunc` completed? what happens if you add a `test_detrend = test_detrend.persist()` and then `client.wait(test_detrend)`? I'm guessing something in here is blowing up your memory, and you're only finding out about it later because of dask's lazy evaluation.

Comment: When I use `dask='allowed'` I find computations are triggered right away as I can see them on the dashboard. So I do not need a `compute()` or `persist()` step.
Besides, the plot is showing the correct answer as the orange curve is the detrended data. 
I anyway ran `test.persist()` and it printed a bunch of numbers showing the calculation had been completed. 
The other command `client.wait(test_detrend)` gave me an error message: `'Client' object has no attribute 'wait'`

Comment: To be clear, in my reply above, I am referring to the working case `(10000,1000,3)`, not the case where the second dimension has a tenfold larger size 10000, which fails and gives me the 'kernel died and is restarting' message.

Comment: oh my bad - it's `dask.distributed.wait` not `client.wait`. and yep, I was expecting it was the larger one that was dying in the apply_ufunc step.

Comment: I get `DoneAndNotDoneFutures(done=set(), not_done=set())` for the smaller problem when I run `dask.distributed.wait`.

For the larger problem, I do not have  an opportunity to run this as I get the error message right after the `apply_ufunc` command finishes "running", as seen in the dashboard. [Am using quotes because I am not sure if it is really running.]